# Spark Streaming Error with snappy compression codec

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, snappy, lzf

I am getting the following exception on running my spark streaming job.

The same job has been running fine since long and when I added two new machines to my cluster I see the job failing with the following exception.

```
16/02/22 19:23:01 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 4229.0 (TID 22594)
java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1257)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:165)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.createCodec(CompressionCodec.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.createCodec(CompressionCodec.scala:60)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$setConf(TorrentBroadcast.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:167)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1254)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec.<init>(CompressionCodec.scala:152)
... 20 more
```

On changing the default compression codec which is snappy to lzf the errors are gone !!

How can I fix this using snappy as the codec ? Is there any downside of using lzf as snappy is the default codec that ships with spark ?

Spark Version is 1.4.0

Comment: I ran yesterday surprisingly into the same problem. I'm not sure that I made some changes in the project at all, but the problem was there (Spark Version 1.6.1).
It was frustrating to not being able to solve the problem after hours of searching... Using LZF solved it for me and hence: thank you for this suggestion! 

It seems that snappy should be [faster](http://blog.erdemagaoglu.com/post/4605524309/lzo-vs-snappy-vs-lzf-vs-zlib-a-comparison-of) than LZF. For me it is now "problem-solved".